# pythonnet - import .net code into python - Error: Could not load file or assembly - (for nested assembly)

Tags: c#, python-3.x, .net-7.0, system.text.json, python.net

the repo with all the code https://github.com/avivs100/pythonnetTest
Environment:

- Pythonnet version: 3.0.3.0
- Python version: 3.11.3
- Operating System: win 10
- .NET Runtime: 7

Details:

I created a simple .NET solution with few projects, 2 class lib and one console application (all in .net7).
The davidProj is a class lib project that contains only 1 class with simple properties.
The consoleApp1 create a David instance and save it to json file with System.Text.Json nuget.
The Test.Infrastructure.DavidUtils is also a class lib project that has 1 static class and 1 static function:

```cs
public static David DeserializeDavidFromJsonString(string davidJson)
    {
//using the System.Text.Json nuget
        var david = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<David>(davidJson) ?? throw new Exception("error");
        return david;
    }
```

I run the .NET app created a JSON file of the David instance and copy the .dll file to new folder and also save the JSON file to that folder.

Now I created in this folder a python file and installed the pythonnet with pip.  This is the code:

```python
import JSON
import clr
clr.AddReference("Test.Infrastructure.DavidUtils")
clr.AddReference("davidProj")

from Test.Infrastructure.DavidUtils import Functions

fullpath = "C:\\Users\\avivshi\\source\\repos\\pythonnetTest\\PythonNetTest\\davidObj.json"
try:
   
    with open(fullpath, "r") as file:
        json_data = json.load(file)
    json_string = json.dumps(json_data)
    print(json_string)
    david = Functions.DeserializeDavidFromJsonString(json_string)
    # Access the properties
    print(f"Name: {david.Name}")
    print(f"Description: {david.Description}")
    print(f"Numbers: {list(david.Numbers)}")
    print(f"Gender: {david.GetGender()}")
    print(f"Type of Gender: {type(david.Gender)}")

except Exception as e:
    print(f"Error: {e}")
```

The error is different with any nuget that i work in the dot net,
if I use the System.Text.Json so this is the error:

```
Error: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Memory, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Memory, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize[TValue](String json, JsonSerializerOptions options)
at Test.Infrastructure.DavidUtils.Functions.DeserializeDavidFromJsonString(String davidJson)
```

if I use the newtonsoft to work with the JSON the same error with different file name that missing

I tried the demos in the GitHub and they work fine also the simple Function and Constructor of David work fine the problem is when I`m using a function with a NuGet dependency.

Comment: Why are you using the *System.Text.Json nuget*?  System.Text.Json is already built into .NET 7.

Comment: It is not meter if install the nugget or not, i still cant use it from the pyhton file.

Comment: i removed from my dot net the install of the nuget system.text.json and still get the same issue at my python script